# Emacs: Apply shell command to top item in kill ring and yank

Tags: emacs

Say I have some text in the clipboard (kill ring) in Emacs. I would like to set up a keyboard shortcut that:

yanks the text after applying a certain shell command on this text: e.g.:

```
   printf $1 | sed 's@^\\@/samba/@;s@\\@/@g'
```

(in this case `$1` would be the text in the clipboard)

How can I do this in Emacs?

Comment: You should write your own elisp function and then bind it to some key combination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a generic `shell-command-on-string`

```el
(defun shell-command-on-str (cmd &optional str)
  "Insert result of calling CMD with STR as input.

STR is current-kill if unspecified.
"
  (interactive (list (read-shell-command "Shell command on region: ")))
  (setq str (or str
                (current-kill 0)))
  (insert (with-temp-buffer
            (insert str)
            (shell-command-on-region (point-min) (point-max) cmd nil 'replace)
            (buffer-string))))
```

You can define your own function that uses it:

```el
(defun my-sed-on-kill ()
  (interactive)
  (shell-command-on-str "sed 's@^\\@/samba/@;s@\\@/@g'"))
```

Comment: Thanks. May I ask, which shell is this executed on?

Answer (score 5):

Unless the shell command is always the same, there's no reason to write any elisp for this:

<kbd>C-y</kbd><kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>M-|</kbd> `sed 's@^\\@/samba/@;s@\\@/@g'` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly, you could take advantage of Emacs `shell-command-on-region`:

```lisp
(defun sed-yank ()
  "Yank the kill ring, then run sed on it"
  (interactive)
  (yank)
  (shell-command-on-region (point) 
                           (mark) 
                           "sed 's@^\\\\@/samba/@;s@\\\\@/@g'" 
                           (current-buffer)
                           t))
```

You can put whatever command you want in the "sed ..." line. The catch is that backslashes need to be escaped inside elisp quotes, so your original `\\` becomes `\\\\`.

That said, unless your shell script is particularly involved, I suspect you'd be better off doing all the processing directly in Emacs, rather than farming it out to sed.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to erase the full buffer and yank the result on it. Is there any way to have it yank on the location of `point`?

Comment: @user815423426 what version of emacs are you using? It works for me on 24.

Comment: Hmm. I'm on the latest stable (just updated a couple weeks ago)

Comment: There was a problem - something in my .emacs was interacting in a helpful way, masking the error. I suspect cua-mode. With vanilla emacs -Q, you need to add a fifth argument to `shell-command-on-region`. Which is a little strange, as this solution is identical to the interactive approach of @phils, which works fine as is.